# Max Bucket Aggregation and Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to do something equivalent to a [Max Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) in elasticsearch 1.7?

Note:

- I cannot switch to elasticsearch 2.x
- Max Bucket Aggregation are available since elasticsearch 2.0.0-beta1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Max Bucket Aggregation` is a type of `Pipeline Aggregation` which can work on the outputs produced from other aggregations rather than from document sets.

The pipeline aggregation support is added in 2.x.

However, you can use the terms aggregation followed by sub-aggregation "[sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)", fetch all the aggregated values in memory and process in-memory to retrieve the results having the maximum metric value for the required field.